Regex for matching numbers >= 150,000 with spaces included not working as expected
I'm trying to create a regex that matches numbers greater than or equal to 150 000, considering spaces as thousand separators. Here is the regex I tried:
^(150\s*000|1[5-9]\d{2}(\s*\d{3})*|[2-9]\d{2}(\s*\d{3})*|\d{1,2}(\s*\d{3})+)$

And here is the JavaScript code I used to test it:
const regex = /^(150\s*000|1[5-9]\d{2}(\s*\d{3})*|[2-9]\d{2}(\s*\d{3})*|\d{1,2}(\s*\d{3})+)$/;
const testStrings = [
    "149 000",
    "151 000",
    "185 000",
    "800 152",
    "15 000",
    "100 000",
    "200 000",
    "250 000 123",
    "100 0000",
    "150 000",
];

testStrings.forEach(testString => {
const matches = testString.match(regex);
if (matches) {
    console.log(`Matched: ${testString}`);
} else {
    console.log(`Did not match: ${testString}`);
}});

However, the results are not as expected:

Did not match: 149 000
Did not match: 151 000
Did not match: 185 000
Matched: 800 152
Matched: 15 000
Did not match: 100 000
Matched: 200 000
Matched: 250 000 123
Did not match: 100 0000
Matched: 150 000

The problem seems to be related the first part of the regex, What am I doing wrong?
I'm using a library where I have to put this regex in HTML because it is the only way to allow this condition :
<input type="radio" required name="myname"  cf-label="Non" value="non" cf-conditional-price="^(150\s*000|1[5-9]\d{2}(\s*\d{3})*|[2-9]\d{2}(\s*\d{3})*|\d{1,2}(\s*\d{3})+)$" />


Are the values in the array always numerical? If so I'd suggest the easier solution would be to coerce them to a numeric type and simply use >= 150_000

Agree with @RoryMcCrossan ... just do a numerical comparison.

1[5-9]\d{2} must be 1[5-9]\d. 100 0000 does not follow your regex logic where you only allow spaces between digit groupings. If you do not care about spaces in the number, simply remove them before validating.

I'm using a library where I can't change the input, it's only strings with formatted digits

Regex is not appropriate for comparing values of strings or numbers. Please consider doing what @RoryMcCrossan suggested

@Jihane then that is perfect for type coercion and mathematical comparison - not regex.

And if you need to match even with any whitespaces between each digit you need to acocunt for them, i.e. ^\s*(?:1\s*5\s*0\s*0\s*0\s*0|1\s*[5-9]\s*\d(?:\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d)*|[2-9]\s*\d\s*\d(?:\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d)*|\d(?:\s*\d)?(?:\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d)+)\s*$ (see demo).

According to your own rules, "100 0000" is not valid - is it meant to be?  You state "not as expected... did not match 100 0000" - but that's correct, it should not match.

Here is a regex that seems to work with your criteria of any number >= 150,000 with spaces replacing the commas:
/\b((1[5-9]\d|[2-9]\d{2}|\d{4,})(\s\d{3})+)\b/

Now I would highly recommend some alternative routes as suggested in the comments, but if you really have to use a regex, this one seems to work fine. Hope this helps!
Here is the finished code replacing your regex:


const regex = /\b((1[5-9]\d|[2-9]\d{2}|\d{4,})(\s\d{3})+)\b/;

const testStrings = [
    "149 000",
    "151 000",
    "185 000",
    "800 152",
    "15 000",
    "100 000",
    "200 000",
    "250 000 123",
    "100 0000",
    "150 000"
];

testStrings.forEach(testString => {
    const matches = testString.match(regex);
    if (matches) {
        console.log(`Matched: ${testString}`);
    } else {
        console.log(`Did not match: ${testString}`);
    }
});




Thank you very much, this works perfectly.  I am aware regex is not the best solution, but the library i'm using limits me to this solution.

You’re welcome, I understand the limitations you are experiencing. Just feels like the library should have some other way to do these types of things. This could most definitely be out of your control though.

Why should you use regex?
We can approach this by converting the string values to numeric values first.
let testStrings = [
    "149 000",
    "151 000",
    "185 000",
    "800 152",
    "15 000",
    "100 000",
    "200 000",
    "250 000 123",
    "100 0000",
    "150 000",
];

testStrings = testStrings.map((str) => Number(str.replace(/\s/g, "")));

testStrings.forEach((value) => {
    if (value >= 150000) {
        console.log(`Matched: ${value}`);
    } else {
        console.log(`Did not match: ${value}`);
    }
});


Your answer is likely voted down because of the additional reason for the regex: I have to put this regex in HTML because it is the only way to allow this condition 

Ah i see, the thread was edited after I responded to it.
